# Perl module Tie::File in a subroutine

Tags: perl

I have this early in my Perl script:

```perl
tie my @y2015, 'Tie::File', "y2015.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2016, 'Tie::File', "y2016.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2017, 'Tie::File', "y2017.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2018, 'Tie::File', "y2018.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2019, 'Tie::File', "y2019.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2020, 'Tie::File', "y2020.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2021, 'Tie::File', "y2021.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2022, 'Tie::File', "y2022.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2022m01, 'Tie::File', "y202201.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2022m02, 'Tie::File', "y202202.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2022m03, 'Tie::File', "y202203.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2022m04, 'Tie::File', "y202204.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2022m05, 'Tie::File', "y202205.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2022m06, 'Tie::File', "y202206.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2022m07, 'Tie::File', "y202207.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2022m08, 'Tie::File', "y202208.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2022m09, 'Tie::File', "y202209.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2022m10, 'Tie::File', "y202210.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @y2022m11, 'Tie::File', "y202211.dat" or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
tie my @roles, 'Tie::File', 'roles-copy.md' or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
```

I also have other further repeated operations on those arrays and file names. So I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
my @datArrays = ('@y2015' , '@y2016' , '@y2017' , '@y2018' , '@y2019' , '@y2020' , '@y2021' , '@y2022' , '@y2022m01' , '@y2022m02' , '@y2022m03' , '@y2022m04' , '@y2022m05' , '@y2022m06' , '@y2022m07' , '@y2022m08' , '@y2022m09' , '@y2022m10' , '@y2022m11' , '@roles');
my @datFiles = ('y2015.dat' , 'y2016.dat' , 'y2017.dat' , 'y2018.dat' , 'y2019.dat' , 'y2020.dat' , 'y2021.dat' , 'y2022.dat' , 'y202201.dat' , 'y202202.dat' , 'y202203.dat' , 'y202204.dat' , 'y202205.dat' , 'y202206.dat' , 'y202207.dat' , 'y202208.dat' , 'y202209.dat' , 'y202210.dat' , 'y202211.dat' , 'roles-copy.md');
sub tieFiles { tie $_[0], 'Tie::File', $_[1] or die "Can't read file: $!\n"; }
foreach my $i (0 .. $#datArrays) { tieFiles ('my $datArrays[$i]', $datFiles[$i]); }
```

but that subroutine `tieFiles` isn't working, as evidenced if I try it just once:

```perl
tieFiles ('my @y2014', 'y2014.dat');
```

I get

> Can't locate object method "TIESCALAR" via package "Tie::File" at ...

So any ideas how to loop my calls to `Tie::File` ?

Comment: `tieFiles` is plural even though it ties one file. `@datArrays` is plural even though it's a single array (although `@datsArray` would make sense if it's an array of "dats").

Answer (score 6):

```perl
tieFiles( 'my $datArrays[$i]', ... )
```

should be

```perl
tieFiles( $datArrays[$i], ... )
```

But Tie::File is an awful awful module to use. It's *insanely* slow. Like up to 30x slower. It can actually use more memory than simply loading the entire file into memory. And it doesn't even make things simpler.

Since you're just getting started, it's the perfect time to dump this module.